# Capitalization with Question Marks

Tags: punctuation

Do you need to capitalize the first word in this situation?

Do you want to eat with me? with Hannah? with Bailey?

or

Do you want to eat with me? With Hannah? With Bailey?

If that is so, why is it like that?

Comment: It is a convention. You should follow your style guide. Modern English Usage suggested you should treat it like a semi-colon for length of pause, and follow with lowercase. In dialogue of course it will often involve change of speaker, paragraph, capital.

Comment: To me it sounds like dialogue so I would go with the capitals.

Comment: If some pieces of software are anything to go by, they automatically switch to upper case for the first letter after a question mark. Maybe I'm old fashioned. but I was taught the "." on a "?" or a "!" acted like a full stop and capitalised the next letter. This is a aide-memoire, not a rule of punctuation.

Comment: I sometimes think the reason why it's not capitalized is because there was an omission happening. They're basically repeating the question but omitting the "unnecessary" part. That's just my guess though.

Comment: If you don't want all those capitals, just collapse the entire utterance into a single sentence: *Do you want to eat with me, with Hannah, or with Bailey?*